# Get notified when Email content invalid or mail is not delievered in php using sendgrid API

Tags: email, sendmail, sendgrid

We are sending about 1 lac email daily using sendgrid API.

But what happen is thousand of mail are undelievered to the recipient.

we want to get the list of these undelievered mail. How is that possible ?

Please suggest some idea or links. becouse I am lost and would really appreciate the assistance.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wow..! finally i made it...

curl code-

```
       curl -X GET
             https://sendgrid.com/api/bounces.get.json?api_user=undefined&api_key=XXXXXXXX
```

and here is my the php code

```
       $ch =curl_init('https://sendgrid.com/api/bounces.get.jsonapi_user=10timeslocal&api_key=10timeslocal');
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
       $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Thanks a lot to everyone tried to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with reading the API docs for [bounces](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/bounces.html), [blocks](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/blocks.html), [invalid emails](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/invalid_emails.html), and [spam reports](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/spam_reports.html).

You can also consume SendGrid's [Event Webhook](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html) which will send you post requests with the information you are looking for.

Comment: I found this  api.sendgrid.com/api/bounces.get.json?api_user=your_sendgrid_username&api_key=your_sendgrid_password&date=1                                here https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/bounces.html but how to integrate it in php file/format [eddiezane](http://stackoverflow.com/users/959953/eddiezane)

Comment: I have curl data but wants to convert it to php code.     CURL DATA----curl -X GEThttps://sendgrid.com/api/bounces.get.json?api_user=undefined&api_key=XXXXXXXX

Answer (score 0):

have a table in the database, that must contains the log of all emails send to users. then later fetch status of these emails via sendgrid apis. then  update their status as success, bounce, invalid.

then for next time don't send emails to that persons whose status in your list are bounce or invalid.

this way you can avoid sending emails to bounces or invalid users.